# MySQL Update Statement from joined table (limited by latest value of that table)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb, mysql-5.5

I'm using MariaDB 5.5

I have 2 tables, I want to update a column in table A based on the information on table B.

Table B has multiple entries for the ID that I'm looking for but each registry has an updated_at column so I just want to get the latest registry.

```
select po_number, sce_status
from infor_order
where po_number = @po
order by updated_at desc;
```

This would result in the following dataset in which I'm only interested on the 'Part Allocated'

[image: DataSetfor Table B]

So what I want to do is update a column in table A searching the latest value of Table B by the "po_number" but when I try just to do the select to test the join I get the 2 values of table B for each registry

```
select b.id, b.PO_NUMBER, b.INFOR_SCE_STATUS, infor.sce_status
from planning_backloguov b
left join (
    select distinct po_number, sce_status
    from infor_order
    order by updated_at desc
) infor on b.PO_NUMBER = infor.po_number
where b.PO_NUMBER = @po;
```

[image: Result from Query]

If I add "limit 1" to the left join subquery I don't get any results from the subquery.

**TL;DR: I just want to update a column from Table A based on the latest value from Table B for a shared ID column between those 2 tables.**

Comment: My question has a SQL query example at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can use a correlated subquery to retrieve the latest `sce_status` from table `infor_order` for the `po_number` of `planning_backloguov`, like so:

```
update planning_backloguov pb
set pb.sce_status = (
    select io.sce_status
    from infor_order io
    where io.po_number = pb.po_number
    order by io.updated_at desc
    limit 1
)
```

---

If you need to update more than one column, then that's a different question. In that case, you need a join and filtering:

```
update planning_backloguov pb
inner join infor_order io on io.po_number = pb.po_number
set 
    pb.sce_status = io.sce_status,
    pb.some_other_column = io.some_other_column  -- change to the actual column name
where io.updated_at = (
    select max(io1.updated_at)
    from infor_order io1
    where io1.po_number = io.po_number
)
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that information, I used that approach and it did work but I need to update more columns from the same tables so something like this:
update planning_backloguov pb
set pb.sce_status = (
    select io.sce_status
    from infor_order io
    where io.po_number = pb.po_number
    order by io.updated_at desc
    limit 1
), pb.sce_order = (
    select io.sce_order
    from infor_order io
    where io.po_number = pb.po_number
    order by io.updated_at desc
    limit 1
)

Comment: @JorgeLimas: mm, that's a quite different question here. I updated my answer with another solution for that.